# Rails posts scaffold not parsing html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to learn rails, and am using my blog as an excuse to do so.

Right now, I'm playing around with the posts scaffold. I get the MVC and the idea behind it, so I was about to recreate it, when I ran accross the following error.

If I enter content like

```
text
text
text
```

in the 'content' tag of posts form, It displays all the text as one block.

```
text text text
```

I thought I could try doing something like

```
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
```

but, it shows

```
<p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p>
```

What I'd like Rails to do is to actually parse the html in content. What would I do to get that to happen?

Here's the New Form Partial, which I used to submit the content

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the Posts Controller as a whole

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.json
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: where you've put those? show us whole model, controller and concerned views to get the whole picture.

Comment: yes, where you want to output the formatted html, use `raw(@obj.content)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent XSS attacks Rails escapes html by default. If you don't want your html escaped you have to use `.html_safe` on the string you don't want escaped. In `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= @post.content.html_safe %>
```

Or a better way would be not to enter `<p>`'s in your content field and use [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) to do the formatting into paragraphs, like this:

```
<%= simple_format(@post.content) %>
```

Of course you could also use a combination of both. E.g. when you have omitted paragraph tags, but *do* have links in your content:

```
<%= simple_format(@post.content.html_safe) %>
```

Note that you can safely use `.html_safe` on content you entered yourself, but don't use it on content that is entered by third parties (like comments) for that would open up your site to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Mischa's answer led me down a rabbit hole of searching, and I also found this gem -- https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails

It adds TinyMCE, a wysiwig editor to a textarea